# Proof verification: $\forall x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi], sin(x) - cos(x) \geq 1$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Would someone be willing to verify the following proof by contradiction?

Theorem: $\forall x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi], sin(x) - cos(x) \geq 1$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that this statement is not true.  Then, $\exists x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi], sin(x) - cos(x) < 1$.

$sin(x) - cos(x) < 1 \Longrightarrow sin^2(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x) + cos^2(x) < 1$

$\Longrightarrow sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) < 1 + 2sin(x)cos(x) \Longrightarrow 0 < sin(x)cos(x)$

On the interval $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi), sin(x) > 0$, and $cos(x) < 0$.  Therefore, $sin(x)cos(x) < 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What does the question have to do with the title? (I don't see the integers $a $ and $b $ anywhere.)

Comment: What about $\sin 1 - \cos 1 \approx 0.30$?

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo - Sorry!  Corrected.

Comment: @gimusi: 1 isn't in the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$.

Comment: How do you eliminate the possibility $\sin x - \cos x < -1$ which would give $(\sin x - \cos x)^2 > 1$?

Comment: I was referring to the initial title on integers. By the way you can’t square the inequality without consider the sign of $\sin x-\cos x$.

Comment: It is not generally true that $a<b\implies a^2<b^2$.

Comment: @ Daniel Schepler: On the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi], -1 \leq cos(x) \leq 0$, and $0 \leq sin(x) \leq 1$, making $sin(x) - cos(x) < -1$ impossible.

Comment: Thank you to all who commented/answered.

Comment: @sphere Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that

$$\cos x=\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} -x\right)$$

and the sum-to-product formulas.

Notably from

$$\sin \theta - \sin \varphi = 2 \sin\left( \frac{\theta - \varphi}{2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\theta + \varphi}{2} \right)$$

we obtain

$$\sin x - cos x=\sin x -\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} -x\right)=2\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \cdot\cos \frac{\pi}{4}=\sqrt2\cdot \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \geq 1$$

whic is true since

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le\pi\iff\frac{\pi}{4}\le x-\frac{\pi}{4}\le\frac{3\pi}{4}\implies \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\ge\frac{\sqrt2}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

In order to square both sides of an equality  we need to make sure that both sides are positive.

Thus if you  mention that $ \forall x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ ,   $$ 0< sin(x) - cos(x) < 1 \Longrightarrow sin^2(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x) + cos^2(x) < 1$$ Then your proof is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following approach: We know $$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b.$$ Look for $c$ such that $c\sin x-c\cos x=\sin(x+a)$ for some $a$. You need $c=\pm\sqrt2/2$. To make life easier, take $c>0$. This gives us $a=-\pi/4$, and $x+a\in[\pi/4,3\pi/4]$. Proceed from here.

Comment: In general, when considering linear combinations $a\cos x+b\sin x$, it is a good idea to find $c$ such that $ac=\cos y$ and $bc=\sin y$ for some $y$, and simplify accordingly.